# WLP: Use both private truststore and server provided truststore

Tags: java, redhat, websphere-liberty, rhel7

## Platform

```
RedHat Enterprise Linux 7
WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.8
```

## Issue

I have several Liberty instances / applications connected to a Liberty Collective Controller, and therefore have ssl and keystores specific to each instance.

At the same time many of the applications connect externally / outbound to different https:// and are in the need of storing root certificates from Commodo, Buypass, Thawte, etc. to avoid `The signer might need to be added to local trust store` and `could not build a valid CertPath`, etc.

## Goal

Use server (Java / RedHat) provided CA root certificate stores unchanged, and use a "pr-instance" truststore where private certificates are imported - in combination.

## Question

Is it possible to combine a "personal" truststore with a server provided truststore (or two), i.e. from the Java installed `/opt/Liberty/java/java_1.8_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file or the RPM package `ca-certificates`

And if so - how?

My current ssl configuration looks like this:

```
<!-- Connection to the collective controller -->
<collectiveMember controllerHost="<server>"
                  controllerPort="<port>" />

<!-- clientAuthenticationSupported set to enable bidirectional trust -->
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig"
     keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
     trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
     clientAuthenticationSupported="true" />

<!-- inbound (HTTPS) keystore -->
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="******"
          location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/key.jks" />

<!-- inbound (HTTPS) truststore -->
<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" password="*****"
          location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/trust.jks" />

<!-- server identity keystore -->
<keyStore id="serverIdentity" password="******"
          location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/serverIdentity.jks" />

<!-- collective truststore -->
<keyStore id="collectiveTrust" password="*******"
          location="${server.config.dir}/resources/collective/collectiveTrust.jks" />
```

Comment: Why? Why not get your server certificate signed by a CA?